# html mobile menu not opening while clicking

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, menu

i have a website in html, where I created a mobile menu , as the container was showing some blank space, I gave it a height, after then the mobile menu is not opening. the code is like below:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.mobile-container {
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #555;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
}

.topnav #myLinks {
  display: none;
}

.topnav a {
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: block;
}

.topnav a.icon {
  background: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-container">

  <!-- Top Navigation Menu -->
  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active" style="color:black">MENU</a>
    <div id="myLinks">
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

however this menu is not opening while I click the icon, can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here, thanks in advance

Comment: But... it *is* opening...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan here its opening, but bro in my localhost when I gave lessheight to the container, its not opening,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add css to the .mobile-container

```
z-index: 1000;
```

you can also try with position style like

```
position: relative;
```

Or

```
position: absolute;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `overflow: visible` to your container?

```
.mobile-container {
  overflow: visible;
```